# Applying FIR filter to data with different sample rates

Tags: filter-design

I have a filter design, and it filters over a 1-2 kHz range.
What should I do if I want to apply it to data with a different sample rate than the one for which it was designed?

Let's say it consists of Bessel and Chebyshev filters. How do I find a function that defines each filter's coefficients at an arbitrary sample rate? Or should I do this by hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mention sampling, you are presumably talking of a digital filter.

The cut-off frequency or half-power frequency of a digital filter is
actually relative to the sampling frequency $f_s$.  If your digital
filter is passing signals in the $1$ kHz to $2$ kHz range when you
feed it a signal sampled at $f_s = 20$ kHz, then the pass band is from
$5\%$ to $10\%$ of $f_s$.  These ratios do not change if
$f_s$ changes to some other value, say $40$ kHz.  The same digital
filter will become a filter with passband $2$ kHz to $4$ kHz without
your having to do anything.

Comment: But I want passband at 1-2 KHz at arbitrary sample rate. I made quick calculations and it seems like coefficients from some filter parts are correlated, but not all. So do I need to reshape filters for fixed sample rates, or there is hope in quest for function/approach that calculates this coefficient for arbitrary sample rate?

Comment: If you want a filter to have fixed pass band at different sampling rates, you need to modify the coefficients accordingly.  The results can be messy: see, for example, [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1101/235) which describes the calculations needed for a very simple filter.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll range filter at fixed rates by hand. I took a look at pointed answer... maybe I'll open my workbook and do some math, but I doubt my skills ;)