# How to design a variable slope highpass filter

Tags: filter-design, frequency-response

I want to design some specific slope highpass filter to enhance  speech; just like $1$ dB/octave,  $2$ dB/octave and more. Is there a method to calculate the coefficients by specific slope?

Comment: uhm, you want that slope specification to be continuous?

Comment: probably check out what a shelving filter is.  google "Audio EQ Cookbook".

Comment: In other words: do you want a piece-wise linear enhancement in the frequency domain? For instance flat in the  low-frequency part, and $+x$ dB above one specfic frequency?

Comment: Thanks for everyone.Actually,what I want is just like the respone in this website.https://support.biamp.com/Tesira/Programming/AEC_in_Tesira  (Pre-Emphasis Filter)  But,I want to design a program to calculate more slope to use in deffient implementation. Further more,I am try to use fft to implement.

Comment: Here's a related question (if you swap poles and zeros) I want to link here because it is so difficult to find otherwise: [IIR filters with variable roll-off](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29040/iir-filters-with-variable-roll-off)

Comment: Likewise, you may find [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56820/15347) to "Pink (1/f) pseudo-random noise generation" useful.

Answer (score 2):

The order of a filter determines its slope. Normally orders are positive integers (1, 2, 3, ...). So the slopes are fixed to multiples of approximately 3db/octave. However, taking the case of a Butterworth filter, someone has applied partial calculus to obtain fractional order Butterworth filters which will effectively allow you to chose the slope. If you do a Google search for *fractional order Butterworth filters* you will get back some papers on the subject. For instance here: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1210/1210.8194.pdf

If you need a different filter type you could apply the same thinking, but the maths may be more complicated for, say, an elliptic filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can design a [Butterworth low pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Transfer_function) and convert it into [high pass filter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). The slope in these filters is Cn dB/decade where C is a constant and n is the filter order. The polynomial for these filters are tabulated.

Comment: How would you design a 2dB/octave high-pass filter using this approach?