# What is best filter to get 1/f(^alpha) that is linear on a log(PSD) vs log(Frequency) plot

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, frequency

I have a white noise signal that I plot on a log(PSD) vs log(frequency) plot.
Now I want to filter that signal with several different filters to to get different alphas (0.5 to 3.0) in the 1/f^alpha sense. I'd like to use the same filter but get different alphas based on the filter parameters. Each log(PSD) vs log(Frequency) plot should be as linear as possible over a wide frequency range.  I am assuming that some filter will provide this.  I need a filter that will produce several alphas near 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0.
Maybe filtering is not the way to go.
Need help.

Comment: I use an FFT approach for arbitrary phase noise profiles that someone had worked out the details for on Matlab’s file exchange site and which I ported to Python- would the details on that help you? With that you can generate noise waveforms with any arbitrary slope including breakpoints.

Comment: Maybe look at the answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56820/41790) and the other answers there as a start.

Comment: Thanks Dan and Ed. As you are aware, as the intensity of filtering increases the temporal autocorrelation increases.  I need the 1/f^alpha types to have larger autocorrelations as alpha also goes from 0 to 3 or so.  I will give your solutions a try.

Comment: Yes, Ben. I am a Matlab user so a file from mathworks file exchange would be very useful.

Comment: Here is the Matlab link but I think Ed’s link is better for cases when a fixed slope is sufficient https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8844-phase-noise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pink ($1/f$) pseudo-random noise generation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/322/pink-1-f-pseudo-random-noise-generation)

Comment: I got Ben's solution working. It uses https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8844-phase-noise.  Had to modify it for my specific application but got it working in short order. One issue: it produces 1/f noise for most of the frequencies but at the very end, it shoots up to a high level again.  Is this expected? Can this be prevented>

Comment: That is, starting at about 245 Hz of a maximum 500 Hz, the curve turns up and at the very high end spikes upward.

Comment: I would post an image from my computer but I can't figure out how. I have 31 reputation points.